# control reaches end of non-void function warning c++

Tags: c++

The following code generate "control reaches end of non-void function" warning at the end of the line. What could possibly gone wrong? From quick search, it seems to have to do with return value.

```
std::vector<csce::point<T>> compute_hull(std::vector<csce::point<T>>& points) const {

        for(std::size_t x=0; x<points.size(); x++){

            for(std::size_t m=1; m<(1<<(1<<x)); m++){
                std::vector<std::vector<csce::point<T>>> hulls;

                for(std::size_t i=0; i<points.size(); i=i+m){
                std::vector<csce::point<T>> chunk;

                if(points.begin()+i+m <= points.end())
                chunk.assign(points.begin()+i,points.begin()+i+m);

                else
                chunk.assign(points.begin()+i,points.end());            
                hulls.push_back(this->graham_scan(chunk));
            }


        std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> hull;

        hull.push_back(this->extreme_hullpt_pair(hulls));

        for(std::size_t i=0; i<m; ++i){
            std::pair<int,int> p = this->next_hullpt_pair(hulls,hull[hull.size()-1]);

            std::vector<csce::point<T>> output;

            if(p==hull[0]){

                for(std::size_t j=0; j<hull.size(); j++){
                    output.push_back(hulls[hull[j].first][hull[j].second]);
                }

                return output;
            }

            hull.push_back(p);


        }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix your formatting and put a `return` statement before the last closing brace.

Comment: Rolled back your edit, since the original form is an important part for the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proper formatting is important to interpret compiler warnings and error messages correctly!**

This pattern in the end of your function definition

```
        }
            }
    }
}
```

is a clear sign your formatting/indentation is seriously screwed up.

However putting a return statement before the last brace should fix the error

```
    // ...
    return points; // <<<<
}
```

---

Also again regarding formatting, always make clear which code blocks are nested (ideally use braces)

```
            if(points.begin()+i+m <= points.end()) {
                chunk.assign(points.begin()+i,points.begin()+i+m); 
            }
            else {
                chunk.assign(points.begin()+i,points.end()); 
            }         
            hulls.push_back(this->graham_scan(chunk)); // Outside if / else
```

Comment: Thanks. That got rid of the warning. However, the output is still unstable. Sometimes the output is correct. Sometimes not. Is there any piece of code that has unstable behavior? Also, thanks for the formatting suggestion.

Comment: @ARSN I'd recommend you inspect your code by stepping through with the debugger. I can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

`compute_hull` is supposed to return a value of type `std::vector<csce::point<T>>` in all code paths, but you don't return anything if the condition `if(p==hull[0]){` always fails. You could return an empty vector in the end of the function for example, just before the last `}`.